Operator: 'Invalid URL' error when trying to sync data
Description:
I am using the AirbyteTriggerSyncOperator in an Apache Airflow DAG to sync data from Airbyte to ClickHouse. However, the task fails, and I get the following error in the logs:
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'localhost/jobs': No scheme supplied. Perhaps you meant https://airbyte-server/jobs?

I get this error when running the dag.
Connection:
Here is the connection configuration in Airflow:
Connection Details:
Here is the configuration of my Airflow connection (airbyte_conn) (Configured in the Airflow UI):
Conn Id: airbyte_conn
Conn Type: HTTP
Host: localhost
Schema: (empty)
Login: airbyte
Password: password (airbyte defaults)
Port: 8001 (airbyte server port - docker)

DAG Task Code:
sync_airbyte_to_clickhouse_task = AirbyteTriggerSyncOperator(
    task_id='sync_airbyte_to_clickhouse',
    airbyte_conn_id='airbyte_conn',
    connection_id='45ce102e-1d33-4834-836a-592d37ee1316',
    asynchronous=False,
    timeout=3600,
    wait_seconds=10,
    dag=dag,
)

Environment:

Docker Compose for orchestration (Airflow, Airbyte, and ClickHouse running in Docker containers)
Apache Airflow 2.x

What I've tried so far:

I checked the configuration of the airbyte_conn connection in Airflow, and it seems correct.
The Airbyte service is up and running, but Airflow doesn't seem to be connecting properly due to the URL issue.


in the host field of the airbyte connection, you need to specify the scheme either http or https followed by the FQDN(fully qualified domain name) and the port for e.g.
https:// followed by host.domain:portnumber/
you can review this airflow docs link: airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-airbyte/stable/… –

Thank you. In the end, I decided to make the call using the same Python code, but now I’m receiving a new error: "connection refused." It seems to happen when I try to call an API that is in another container. I don't understand why this is happening, as I have the ports correctly assigned, the containers are on the same network, and the docker-compose file is well-structured and reviewed. I truly feel very lost.
